# PTP (or NTP) and Domain Controller clock sync

Tags: windows, domain, time-synchronization, ptp

We need a high precision (1ms) clock synchronization across multiple machines which are part of the domain. The idea is to use a PTP solution.

Is it possible to setup a computer which is part of the domain to use a different time synchronization mechanism? Would domain clock synchronization not interfere with it? Can it be disabled if so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just stop default Windows Time synchronization service and use Your own. It Ok as long as time in sync with domain in 5 min window.

Answer (score 1):

Windows supports synching time with non-domain servers.  Just be aware that if the time interferes radically with the domain time, kerberos tickets will stop working and shares/printers/etc. will start to fail.